# Command not found in C++ Makefile for CS

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to make a makefile for my c++ project, but I'm getting this error:

```
flip1 ~/cs162/program2 1049$ make
c card.cpp
make: c: Command not found
make: [card.o] Error 127 (ignored)
c deck.cpp
make: c: Command not found
make: [deck.o] Error 127 (ignored)
g++ card.o deck.o hand.o main.o -o prog2
g++: error: card.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: deck.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [prog2] Error 1
```

and my makefile looks like this:

```
CC = g++
exe_file = prog2
$(exe_file): card.o deck.o hand.o main.o
    $(CC) card.o deck.o hand.o main.o -o $(exe_file)

card.o: card.cpp
    $(cc) -c card.cpp
deck.o: deck.cpp
    $(cc) -c deck.cpp
hand.o: hand.cpp
    $(CC) -c hand.cpp
main.o: main.cpp
    $(CC) -c main.cpp

clean:
    rm -f *.out *.o $(exe_file)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue being my compiler target `CC = g++` used capital Cs and on lines 7 and 9 I had lowercase cs.